# RecyclerView крашит программу

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я хочу загрузить в recyclerview список фотографий, делаю это следующим кодом(код страницы):

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.photosList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listAll = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter_photos = new Adapter_Photos(this, listAll);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_photos);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PhotosPage.this, MarathonsActivity.class));
        }
    });

    final int[] marathons_cnt = new int[1];
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MarathonsAmount").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            marathons_cnt[0] = snapshot.getValue(int.class);
            int photoid = 0;
            while (bl[0]) {
                bl[0] = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < marathons_cnt[0]; ++i){
                    final _Post[] post = new _Post[1];
                    DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Marathons").child(String.valueOf(i)).child("Photos").child(String.valueOf(photoid));
                    reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            post[0] = snapshot.getValue(_Post.class);
                            if (post[0] != null) {
                                bl[0] = true;
                                listAll.add(post[0]);
                                adapter_photos.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                ++photoid;
            }
        }
    });
```

(код адаптера):

```
Context context;

ArrayList<_Post> list;

public Adapter_Photos(Context context, ArrayList<_Post> list){
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    _Post post = list.get(position);
    final String[] name = {""};
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(post.authorId).child("MainInfo").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
            name[0] += dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            name[0] += " ";
            name[0] += dataSnapshot.child("secondName").getValue(String.class);
        }
    });
    final String[] mara = {""};
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Marathons").child(String.valueOf(post.marathonId)).child("MainInfo").child("Name").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
            mara[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }
    });
    holder.author.setText(name[0]);
    holder.marathon.setText(mara[0]);
    holder.likes.setText(String.valueOf(post.likes));
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(Uri.parse(post.link))
            .into(holder.photo);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    RoundedImageView photo;
    TextView author, marathon, likes;
    ImageView like_img;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        photo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_photo);
        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
        marathon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_marathon);
        likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_likes_cnt);
        //comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_comments_cnt);
        like_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_like);
    }
}
```

Логи:

```
2022-03-20 23:37:39.909 12725-12725/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.photo42_project, PID: 12725
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7079)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Пробовал дебажить и смотреть по логу, но результатов ноль... Заранее спасибо

Comment: без лога только при запуске можно понять в чем беда хоть как-то, постарайтесь лог вытащить все-таки

Comment: @Andrew логи прикрепил

Comment: Вы в `onCreateViewHolder` создаёте вью и холдер, но возвращаете `null`